# Illegal instruction (core dumped) while importing mxnet

Tags: python-2.7, mxnet

I am getting "Illegal instruction (core dumped)" exception while calling import mxnet. I am using CUDA 9.0, and did mxnet installation using anaconda. My python version is 2.7. As a side note, CUDA 10.0 is also installed on my machine.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Most likely, the issue is caused by the different version of CUDA.
Please try to build the MXNet from the source.

Comment: Yes, building from source solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The "illegal instruction (core dumped)" is usually caused by MXNet loading different shared libraries than was originally built with, CUDA, OpenMP, etc. One solution is to build directly from source on your own system.

For example:

```
    git clone --recursive https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet.git
    cd incubator-mxnet
    echo "USE_OPENCV = 1" >> ./config.mk
    echo "USE_BLAS = openblas" >> ./config.mk
    echo "USE_CUDA = 1" >> ./config.mk
    echo "USE_CUDA_PATH = /usr/local/cuda" >> ./config.mk
    echo "USE_CUDNN = 1" >> ./config.mk
    make -j $(nproc)
```

Full install instructions are available on the MXNet website: http://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/versions/master/install/index.html?platform=Linux&language=Python&processor=CPU